# Cross Platform Nuget Library

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, nuget

I have a xamarin forms app that has a common project and one android , one ios and one uwp apps. These all three apps have a scanner detection service which have different implementation. My goal is to make a nuget library which will have IScannerService.cs this interface will have few function and have a different implementaion for android,ios and uwp. I just then need to instal the nuget library. and it will automatically map uwp scanner implementation from nuget to the required project.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Follow instructions in docs [Steps to Create a Cross-Platform Library NuGet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/nuget-multiplatform-libraries/platform-specific#steps-to-create-a-cross-platform-library-nuget).

Comment: I created a [multi-target nuget package](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.MVVM) a while ago

Answer (score 0):

Follow instructions in docs [Steps to Create a Cross-Platform Library NuGet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/nuget-multiplatform-libraries/platform-specific#steps-to-create-a-cross-platform-library-nuget).

Comment: Its only for the android and ios. I also need for the uwp and wpf

Comment: Ah. You could add an issue at [nugetizer issue](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+label%3AArea%3ANuGetizer), asking if those platforms will be added. OR wait until MAUI gets close to release - MAUI handles multi-platform internally in a better way. (I don't yet see any  instructions for turning a MAUI app into a Nuget. Too early I think.)